# Функция SendInput: чужое окно игнорирует программные события.

Tags: winapi, windows

Используя функцию SendInput, программа имитирует действия мыши (клавы) в чужом окне, это чужое окно как-то фильтрует эти события и определяет было ли это действие программным или же это реальное нажатие (перемещение) мыши и игнорирует програмные события.

Как сделать так, чтоб он реагировало на программные события?

Answer (score 1):

Отправка сообщений функцией [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Первый параметр дескриптор окна, второй - тип сообщения. Остальные параметры содержат *специфичные для каждого сообщения* дополнительные данные. 
Вам нужны разделы [Mouse Input Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Keyboard Input Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468861%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: SendMessage(WHandle,WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK,0,0);
Почему-то не реагирует? может надо фокус какой нить установить?

Comment: Посмотрите описание [WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). lParam у вас допустимый, задает точку (0,0), а wParam?

Comment: Все равно не реагирует, как правильно надо ?

Answer (score 0):

проверьте какие сообщения посылает сама винда окошкам прогой, к примеру Spy++ из стандартной поставки Microsoft VisualStudio